# How to Add Gstreamer Plugin on Mac when installed from Tutorials

Tags: xcode, macos, ffmpeg, gstreamer

I basically have **two** installs of gstreamer on my Mac OS X machine:
The one that works perfectly was installed following this tutorial (http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Mac+OS+X) and downloading and installing the Developer SDK and using XCode.  All tutorials work well.

I *also* have a local version installed with Homebrew but video playback does not work on that version (see SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24663520/gstreamer-gst-launch-sample-mac-osx-plays-audio-but-not-video)

SO, I'm trying to install the **FFMPEG plugin** into the *working* xcode dev system so that I can use FFDEC_H263 in a project.

I tried simply copying the related .SO files (e.g. libgstffmpg.so) from the homebrew (cellar) location to the

```
 /Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.Framework/Versions/0.10/lib/gstreamer-0.10/
```

directory and changing permissions.   However, that gives me a "*Caught a segmentation fault while loading plugin file*" error when building any code.

I also noticed that in the Xcode directory mentioned above, all of the plugins have a related .a and .la files in the \static subdirectory...  Those same files don't exist in the homebrew version.

So, what is the proper way to install a plugin when you've started with the developer SDK for Mac OSX?